# How to reference AWS HTTP API (v2) in CloudFormation template for CloudWatch Dashboard?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I am trying to build an AWS HTTP API (API Gateway v2) using the serverless framework and I also want to create a CloudWatch Dashboard which shows metrics about this HTTP API using a CloudFormation template for CloudWatch Dashboard.

According to AWS, they don't support HTTP API metrics by API NAME. They only support it by API ID. The problem is that sometimes the API ID changes when you deploy so it's not reliable, I can't hardcode it into the CloudWatch template. Is there any to reference the HTTP API from the serverless file and retrieve its ID so it can be passed to the CloudWatch CloudFormation template?

Below is a snippet of my code:

```yaml
provider:
  httpApi:
    metrics: true

resources:
  Resources:
    MyDashboard:
      Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard
      Properties: 
        DashboardName: MyDashboard
        DashboardBody: '
        {
          "widgets": [
            {
            "type": "metric",
            "properties": {
                "metrics": [
                    [
                        "AWS/ApiGateway",
                        "4xx",
                        "Resource",
                        "/{proxy+}",
                        "Stage",
                        "$default",
                        "Method",
                        "ANY",
                        "ApiId",
                        "f8d7a6fd8", ============> I want this to be a variable such as ${self:provider.myApiId}
                        {
                            "yAxis": "left"
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "view": "bar",
                "stacked": false,
                "region": "us-west-2",
                "period": 300,
                "stat": "Sum",
                "setPeriodToTimeRange": true
            }
          }
          ]
        }
        '
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Sub function:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html

In this case:

```yaml
      DashboardBody: 
        !Sub |
        {
          "widgets": [
            {
            "type": "metric",
            "properties": {
                "metrics": [
                    [
                        "AWS/ApiGateway",
                        "4xx",
                        "Resource",
                        "/{proxy+}",
                        "Stage",
                        "$default",
                        "Method",
                        "ANY",
                        "ApiId",
                        "${self:provider.myApiId}",
                        {
                            "yAxis": "left"
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "view": "bar",
                "stacked": false,
                "region": "us-west-2",
                "period": 300,
                "stat": "Sum",
                "setPeriodToTimeRange": true
            }
          }
          ]
        }
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but how does that provider know what myApiId means? The question says that we must retrieve that id dynamically.